# Failed to test nestedReduce2.cu from book Professional CUDA C Programming

Tags: cuda

I am reading the book *Professional CUDA C Programming*. I've downloaded the source codes from [Wiley](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Professional+CUDA+C+Programming-p-9781118739310#downloads-section), the file has been tested was *chapter03/nestedReduce2.cu*. Or the file could be found at [github](https://github.com/deeperlearning/professional-cuda-c-programming/blob/master/examples/chapter03/nestedReduce2.cu).

I've made the *.cu* file by its *Makefile* as well as simple command:

```bash
nvcc -o nestedReduce2 ./nestedReduce2.cu -rdc=true
```

The output was like:

```bash
./nestedReduce2 starting reduction at device 0: Quadro RTX 4000 array 1048576 grid 2048 block 512
cpu reduce      elapsed 0.000858 sec cpu_sum: 1048576
gpu Neighbored      elapsed 0.000404 sec gpu_sum: 1048576 <<<grid 2048 block 512>>>
gpu nested      elapsed 0.044057 sec gpu_sum: 1048576 <<<grid 2048 block 512>>>
gpu nestedNosyn     elapsed 0.019464 sec gpu_sum: 1048576 <<<grid 2048 block 512>>>
gpu nested2     elapsed 0.001051 sec gpu_sum: 946688 <<<grid 2048 block 512>>>
Test failed!
```

How to solve this problem? Is there some update for CUDA recursive programming since the last update of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have that book and have never read it.  I don't really know what is in the book, so my response is directed to the code posted on [the github site](https://github.com/deeperlearning/professional-cuda-c-programming/blob/master/examples/chapter03/nestedReduce2.cu) and nothing else.  I'm unable to make any statements about a book I don't have and have never read.

Concerning the kernel in question:

```
__global__ void gpuRecursiveReduce2(int *g_idata, int *g_odata, int iStride,
                                    int const iDim)
{
    // convert global data pointer to the local pointer of this block
    int *idata = g_idata + blockIdx.x * iDim;

    // stop condition
    if (iStride == 1 && threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        g_odata[blockIdx.x] = idata[0] + idata[1];
        return;
    }

    // in place reduction
    idata[threadIdx.x] += idata[threadIdx.x + iStride];

    // nested invocation to generate child grids
    if(threadIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.x == 0)
    {
        gpuRecursiveReduce2<<<gridDim.x, iStride / 2>>>(g_idata, g_odata,
                iStride / 2, iDim);
    }
}
```

I believe it should be fairly evident for correctness, that the child kernel launch:

```
        gpuRecursiveReduce2<<<gridDim.x, iStride / 2>>>(g_idata, g_odata,
                iStride / 2, iDim);
```

should not be allowed to execute until the preceding parent reduction:

```
    // in place reduction
    idata[threadIdx.x] += idata[threadIdx.x + iStride];
```

is complete.  Both items potentially span up to half the entire dataset, and therefore depend on results from multiple blocks (to be complete, for correctness).

On my V100 GPU (CUDA 11.4), the code gives the expected result.  However as OP has demonstrated, it may not give the expected result in all scenarios.

In order to be confident of correct results, we would need something like a grid-wide sync, in between the parent reduction step, and the child kernel execution, for each sweep phase (except the last, since there is only 1 thread per block in that case, and so all blocks terminate before reaching the child kernel launch.)

Unfortunately, the cooperative groups grid-wide sync is not supported with CUDA dynamic parallelism (CDP).

The other grid-wide sync formally provided by CUDA is the kernel launch boundary.  Therefore:

> How to solve this problem?

my suggestion would be to dispense with CDP launches, and use a set of (non-recursive) kernel launches driven by a for-loop in host code.  For someone at the level of study indicated here, this should be a trivial refactoring, so I will not present it here.

Additional discussion:

In particular, we could surmise that a case where the GPU is "smaller" (i.e. fewer SMs) and the grid size is "larger" might be a problem.  This might give rise to a situation where child kernel blocks are executing prior to the completion of some parent kernel blocks.

Coupled with this, a question might be asked "is there any characteristic of null stream behavior (e.g. synchronization) between the parent kernel null stream and the child kernel null stream that would (or should have) created the desired ordering?"  The answer is no.  You can refer to [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#streams-cdp), where null stream behavior of CDP kernels is discussed.

In my view it is clear that the child kernel NULL stream does not synchronize with the parent kernel null stream.  As an additional thought experiment, we should keep in mind that the documentation [states](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization) that a parent kernel is not considered complete until all child kernels are complete.   Coupled with that, if we assumed null stream synchronizing behavior between parent and child, it would immediately give rise to deadlock.  So we reject that hypothesis.

For additional inspection, we can derive a test case to convince ourselves that a parent kernel null stream and child kernel null stream do not interact:

```
$ cat t2099.cu
#include <iostream>

__global__ void child(int *d, int val){

  *d = val;
}

__global__ void parent(int *d, int val){

  *d = val;
  if (blockIdx.x == 1048577) child<<<1,1>>>(d, 1);
}

int main(){

  int *d;
  cudaMallocManaged(&d, sizeof(d[0]));
  parent<<<2*1048576, 1>>>(d, 0);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  std::cout << d[0] << std::endl;
}


$ nvcc -o t2099 t2099.cu -rdc=true
$ ./t2099
0
$
```

In the above simplified test case, we are launching a parent kernel of ~2M blocks, where all parent kernel blocks set a variable to zero, and the child kernel launched from a single block picked arbitrarily sets the variable to 1.

If there were parent/child synchronization, we would expect the variable to be 1 at conclusion.  Since it is 0, we conclude that there is no synchronization between parent and child kernel.  The child kernel (block) somehow "intermixed" with the execution of the parent kernel blocks.  (the "intermixing" is not in any way guaranteed by CUDA, but we could surmise that one reason the block scheduler might choose to intermix is because the parent kernel block is not complete until its child kernel block is complete.  Therefore, from a throughput perspective, it might be advantageous to make forward progress on the child kernel, in the midst of the parent kernel.)

This discussion and experiment help to reinforce the idea that the presented code needs/requires a grid-wide sync for correctness, and neither the code itself nor the CDP mechanism provide any guarantee of that.

(for completeness, the test case I presented is not *guaranteed* to produce 0 and it may not produce 0 if you run it in your machine.  The fact that it does produce 0 in at least one test setup - mine - is sufficient for the argument.  In my test case, if I change the number of blocks launched to 1048578, then the output changes from 0 to 1.)

Comment: Thank you. I've got the idea that the root cause of this issue is that some blocks of parent grid had not completed when the some of child blocks was executing `+=` operations. I've tried grid-sync by atomic operations. It worked although I am not sure if it's good practice.